# Which content providers support MPEG-DASH

Tags: manifest, mpeg-dash, mpd

I am looking for real content for MPEG-DASH - 
Does anybody know which content providers use mpd manifests for their Vod / Adaptive streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We deployed e.g. the following customers using MPEG-DASH:

- http://www.flimmit.at
- http://www.kronehit.tv
- http://www.sonostream.tv
- http://www.genflix.co.id

You can also find a lot of MPEG-DASH streams at http://www.dash-player.com and http://www.bitcodin.com

Answer (score 1):

youtube and netflix are probably the biggest names that use it. There is a multitude of smaller or regional players that also use it. All major streaming servers support it so one can start with dash quite quickly.

Comment: From an article that published last year - Netflix support media file format but not yet mpd manifests. has that changed?

Comment: AFAIK netflix uses dash + some custom extensions to the MPD.

Comment: I think you will find youtube and netflix use some of the fundamentals behind DASH e.g. MSE, EME, CENC and ISO BMFF but not so really DASH itself